# Promise didn't get then branch

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, promise, angular-promise

I've implemented this function for updating my user on firebase, the problem is that it never calls the "then" function... any suggestion on this issue?

The user was correctly updated in the database, and if I try to implement the "then" branch directly on the function, it is fired.

EDIT () :

```
     // Proseguo con aggiornamento
     this.statoUtente.updateCurrentUser(uteIn).then(() => {

          <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< program never call this >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

          console.log('Risposta da Promise') ;  
          // Dopo l'aggiornamento chiedo di completare le informazioni mancanti
          this.nomeTemplate = 'updateUserForm' ;
          this.helperset = 2 ;
          this.wait = false ;
          this.error = '' ;
      })




updateCurrentUser(UteIn : TipoSingoloUtente) : Promise<any> {

  let Promessa = new Promise<any>(observer => {
    let IDUtente = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid ;
    console.log(IDUtente) ;
    if ((IDUtente) && ( IDUtente.trim() != '' )) {
      UteIn.ID = IDUtente ;
      observer(this.db.object('users/' + IDUtente).set(UteIn))
    } else {
      console.log('null null null') ;
      Promise.resolve(false) ;
    }
  }) ;

  return Promessa ;

}
```

Comment: You never resolve your promise. `return` in a promise constructor function does not resolve the promise. You need to call the `observer` function with your result as the argument.

Comment: Why are you using promises at all? Nothing in that code looks asynchronous.

Comment: @Bergi I'd assume `this.db.object('users/' + IDUtente).set(UteIn)` would be async. But if that returns a promise then you can just return that and `Promise.resolve(false)` in the other branch.

Comment: @TylerSebastian... yep, the this.db... return a promise... if i set the "then" branch inside the function, it get fire... if i leave the code as my question... it never call the then branch outside the function... i've updated the "other branch with the promise resolve"

Comment: @CRice  Great dude, i just update the code as : "observer(this.db.object('users/' + IDUtente).set(UteIn))" and it get works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need

```
updateCurrentUser(UteIn: TipoSingoloUtente) {
  const IDUtente = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid;
  if (IDUtente && IDUtente.trim() != '') {
    UteIn.ID = IDUtente;
    return this.db.object('users/' + IDUtente).set(UteIn);
  } else {
    console.log('null null null');
    return Promise.resolve(false);
  }
}
```

you don't need to wrap it in a `Promise` constructor. `this.db.object...` returns a `Promise` and `Promise.resolve(...)` returns a `Promise` so you're good.

Comment: thanks, also this solution works ( and it's more simple than mine )

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the promise that you're creating manually.  There is no need for it.  You can work with only the promise returned by this:

```
this.db.object('users/' + IDUtente).set(UteIn)
```

When that promise resolves, you can be sure that the database is updated.